# Homepage showing up as "index of \" page

Tags: assets, php, css

I am uploading a repo that works fine on a staging server to a live server. When doing so however the homepage is showing as "index of \" page with the public and readme.md directories showing. Like so

[image]

When i click on the public link it brings me to  the page, however it has no public assets or css. it is just HTML.

[image]

The database is linked properly. their are no errors that are showing as it is on dev mode. What can I do to fix this?

Here is the file structure in my home directory which is proper.

[image]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you please share how you have managed the `index.php` and `craft` folder inside your home directory

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the file stucture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, I guess it wasn't craft cms related.

I had to update my apache2 site-enabled config file!

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is a quick solution to your problem:

1. Move all your public files to the same directory where your craft folder is.
2. Change your Craft path in index.php file.